# Question about operators on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\cal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_m$ a sequence of orthonormal projections such that $P_iP_j=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $P_1+P_2+\cdots+P_m=I$. Then $\|\sum^m_{k=1}P_kTP_k\|\leq\|T\|$ for all $T\in \cal{B}(H)$. Is it true? If it is true, how to prove?

Comment: In fact $\|\sum\limits_k P_kTP_k\| = \max\limits_k \|P_kTP_k\|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x\in H$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\|\sum_k P_kTP_kx\|^2 
&=
\langle \sum_j P_jTP_jx,\sum_k P_kTP_kx \rangle
= \sum_{j,k} \langle TP_jx,P_jP_kTP_kx\rangle \\
&= \sum_{j} \langle P_jTP_jx,P_jTP_jx\rangle
\leq \|T\|^2 \sum_{j} \langle P_jx,P_jx\rangle \\
& = \|T\|^2 \sum_{j} \langle P_jx,x\rangle
= \|T\|^2  \langle \sum_{j} P_jx,x\rangle \\
&= \|T\|^2  \|x\|^2.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: It is a nice proof, thank you!